# Sharing Django Models with Foreign Fields across apps

Tags: django, django-models, dry

I have a Django project with two apps that are almost identical but for a number of reasons, I'd like to keep them separate. To keep things DRY, I created a base_model file.

```
# base_model.py
from django.db import models

class ModelOne(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class ModelTwo(models.Model):
    name   = models.CharField()
    friend = models.ForeignKey(ModelOne)
```

My two apps are called app1 & app2.

How do I import these models so that essentially I'll have 4 tables for these two models?

Thanks.

**UPDATE 1**

The reason why I need two versions of these 2 models is that I want to keep them in a separate database as they have separate uses.

For example, let's say I own a home with furniture and as well as a furniture store. I want to keep a separate list for both sets of furniture. The furniture in my home will be kept on a home server, while my store furniture will be kept on a work server. In addition, I'll also like to keep track of the color of the furniture, so that will be a separate table.

```
# base_model.py
from django.db import models

class Color(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class FurnitureBase(models.Model):
    name   = models.CharField()
    color  = models.ForeignKey(Color)
```

For the store app, I need to keep track of pricing, manufacturer, etc. For the home app, I'll need to keep track of usage, age, etc.

Comment: You are going to need to give some more context here. Why do they *need* to be separate?

Answer (score 0):

These two models should be defined as `abstract = True` under Meta.  Then in each of your two apps, sub-class to create concrete versions in each app.  Something like:

app1/models.py:

```
class App1ModelOne(base_models.ModelOne):
    pass


class App1ModelTwo(base_models.ModelTwo):
    pass
```

Read abstract base classes and model inheritance in django's docs for more information: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes

Comment: ah yes, I didn't see that.  You'll have to duplicate that FK relationship on each of the concrete implementations.

Comment: As alternative of FK duplicating the OP may use the generic relation. But as @lego-stormtroopr points we don't know the context of the task.